# Combining select field and integer field in flask

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm building a flask app and I am taking an input from the user that has a number and a choice from a menu (daily, weekly, monthly, annually) ..

That's currently my code for the HTML page

```
{% for field in form %} 
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="">{{field.label}}</label>
  {{field}} /
  <select name="frequency" id="">
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <option value="week" selected>Week</option>
    <option value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="year">Year</option>
  </select>
</div>
{%endfor%}
```

python code where i need the value of select option menu:

```
 if form.validate_on_submit():
    for field in form:
        weight=getItemTotalGrams(getItemWeight(field.name), field.data, request.form.get('frequency'))
```

where getItemTotalGrams takes 3 integers and getItemWeight takes name of item and returns its weight.
Item is an object that has 2 attributes, name and weight.

so, I am able to get the value from the field to use it in python later but i don't know how to get the value from the select option menu, so i thought about including it in the field but couldn't find a way to do so.

So my question is either:

- is there a way where i can add a select field and integer field in WTF-Forms to connect the 2 input in one field?
- or how to get the value of the select option menu to use it in python?

Comment: if you use `for`-loop to create many `<select> ` then every select need unique name `name="frequency1"`, `name="frequency2"`, etc. Or use it with field name  `name="frequency{{ field.name }}"`, And later you can get it as `request.form.get(f'frequency{field.name}')`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to combine multiple fields in a nested form. The [`FormField`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FormField) gives you the opportunity to do this. Several groups of this type can also be created in connection with a field of the [`FieldList`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList) type.

When the values are queried, a dict or a list of dicts is returned.

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import FieldList, FormField, IntegerField, SelectField, SubmitField

class WeightForm(FlaskForm):
    weight = IntegerField()
    frequency = SelectField(
        choices=[
            ('day', 'Day'),
            ('week', 'Week'),
            ('month', 'Month'),
            ('year', 'Year'),
        ],
        default='week'
    )

    class Meta:
        # No need for csrf token in this child form
        csrf = False

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    weights = FieldList(FormField(WeightForm), min_entries=1)
    submit = SubmitField()

@app.route('/example', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def example():
    form = MyForm(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.weights.data)
    return render_template('example.html', **locals())
```

```html
<form method="post">
  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  {% for nested in form.weights -%}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ nested.form.weight.label }}
    {{ nested.form.weight }}
    {{ nested.form.frequency }}
  </div>
  {% endfor -%}
  {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Comment: I followed your steps, they made sense to me. But I encountered an error and have no idea how to solve it
AssertionError: Field must be unbound, not a field class.
please note that i have used WeightForm more than one time inside MyForm since I have more than one item to get its weight.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the error. From a distance it's hard to tell why the error occurs.
I'm assuming you're passing an input field somewhere that isn't one. You may be passing a form directly instead of wrapping it in a FormField, or the class is being passed instead of an object due to missing parentheses.